how to send batch message to pubsub from apache beam
I have a beam pipeline that make some transformation, and I want to write the data to pubsub and order to be processed by other pipelines.
how to send message to pubsub using apache beam ? 
I saw that there is the apache_beam.io.WriteToPubSub but it only works for streaming pipeline, in my case its a batch one
